# How do i format multiple USB drives at once in CMD?

Tags: windows-10, usb, cmd.exe, script, format

i work at a school. And when we have examns, we provide the students with USB sticks.

After the examns we need to format all the drives. So far we've been using the following CMD script

How ever, i need to press enter for each drive. Is there a way to skip the "press enter to format"?

````
ECHO PRESS ANY KEY TO START DRIVE FORMATTING OR CLOSE THIS WINDOW NOW
PAUSE
rem SET DRIVES[0]=D:
SET DRIVES[1]=E:
SET DRIVES[2]=F:
SET DRIVES[3]=G:
SET DRIVES[4]=H:
SET DRIVES[5]=I:
SET DRIVES[6]=J:
SET DRIVES[7]=K:
SET DRIVES[8]=L:
SET DRIVES[9]=M:
SET DRIVES[10]=N:
SET DRIVES[11]=O:
rem SET DRIVES[12]=P:
rem SET DRIVES[13]=Q:
rem SET DRIVES[14]=R:
rem SET DRIVES[15]=S:
rem SET DRIVES[16]=T:
rem SET DRIVES[17]=U:
rem SET DRIVES[18]=V:
rem SET DRIVES[19]=W:
rem SET DRIVES[20]=X:
rem SET DRIVES[21]=Y:
rem SET DRIVES[22]=Z:
ECHO PRESS ANY KEY TO START DRIVE FORMATTING OR CLOSE THIS WINDOW NOW.  LAST CHANCE!
PAUSE

FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS==" %%D IN ('SET DRIVES[') DO (

REM IF EXIST %%E\KILLSWITCH.INI ECHO FORMATTING %%E
REM IF EXIST %%E\KILLSWITCH.INI 
    FORMAT %%E /FS:FAT32 /V:BESTSCHOOLEVER-USB /X /Q 
REM & ECHO > %%E\KILLSWITCH.INI

)
ECHO PROCESS FINISHED
PAUSE ```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066396/windows-format-command-line-skip-enter-current-volume-and-proceed-with-for

Comment: I assume the *killswitch.ini* bit is the failsafe? Considering the cataclysmic damage this batch file could do, I would add a few more safeguards, like checking the value of `%computername%` and `%username%`, so it's only you on your machine.

Comment: Thats actually a great idea.

However, im not too familiar with CMD. How would i implement this? :)

Comment: You can an IF statement combined with [goto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/goto). So `IF %computername% == bobs_pc goto FORMAT` (where `:FORMAT` is the label for the part with the formatting command), the line after this would only be parsed if that statement is false, if you use a `goto :END` there it'll immediately exit the script (that one is hardcoded, you can also add a `:WARNING` label below the :FORMAT section and use `ECHO` to warn the reader that this is the wrong computer).

Comment: Sorry if im being stupid now. But as i understand it, the `IF %computername% == Thisismy_pc goto FORMAT`
can just be placed in the very beginning of the script? or should i delete / edit anything?

Comment: You can add that to the beginning or right before you do destructive stuff like FORMAT (`SET` is also harmless, you're just setting up variables). If you add a :WARNING section, make sure you put a `goto END` right before that label, so that it gets skipped if format WAS run (and a warning is not necessary).

Comment: Note that your initial failsafe (the killswitch.ini stuff) is not enabled either right now, `rem` (*"remark"*) at the front of a line means it doesn't get parsed.

Comment: Aha. I'll give it a go! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: No worries, good luck :)

Comment: Hello hello :P 

Now that i altered the script, it wont work. Any ideas? i just added `IF %username% == myusername goto FORMAT`

Comment: Is there a line that just says `:FORMAT` in the script?

Comment: wait.... yes.... im blind xD Sorry!

Comment: So did you manage to get everything to work now? :)

Comment: Havnt been to work for a week due to illness. But i'll try today :-)

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off

for /f usebackq^tokens^=^4delims^=^>^< %%i in =;(`
     wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get name /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
        `);= do if exist "%%~i\killswitch.ini" =;(
             echo\Formatting %%~i...
             <nul echo\ | format %%~i /fs:fat32 /v:School-USB /x /q | findstr ") : ,"
             cd.> %%~i\KILLSWITCH.INI
             start "" /w RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll
            );=
```

---

If the presence of the `killswitch.ini` file in the root folder of the drive is enough to filter the target drive for formatting, then use that as a drive lookup, and a redirect `|` to skip confirmation.

---

If that's not enough, you can also pre-filter by `VolumeName='SCHOOL-USB'`:

```bat
@echo off

for /f usebackq^tokens^=^4delims^=^>^< %%i in =;(`
     wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType=2 and VolumeName='SCHOOL-USB'" get name /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
        `);= do if exist "%%~i\killswitch.ini" =;(
             echo\Formatting %%~i...
             <nul echo\ | format %%~i /fs:fat32 /v:School-USB /x /q | findstr ") : ,"
             cd.> %%~i\KILLSWITCH.INI
             start "" /w RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll
            );=
```

---

If you need to use it for several flash drives, then a loop via `:label/loop` could help and give you time to switch devices:

```bat
@echo off

set "_check_USB=wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType=2 and VolumeName='SCHOOL-USB'""

%:^(
2>nul %_check_USB% | find ":" >nul || timeout 5 && goto %:^(

for /f usebackq^tokens^=^4delims^=^>^< %%i in =;(`
    %_check_USB% ^| find "VALUE"`);= do if exist "%%~i\killswitch.ini" =;(
         echo\Formatting %%~i...
         <nul echo\ | format %%~i /fs:fat32 /v:School-USB /x /q | findstr ") : ,"
         cd.> %%~i\KILLSWITCH.INI
         start "" /w RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll
        );= & goto %:^(
```

---

Comment: Does this skip C:?

Comment: This is for flash drives only, and yes, this will skip local disks

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! :)